# Passing values to Vue component with Blade

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I have Vue2, running with Laravel 5.5. Trying to pass values to a component by I keep getting errors from VUE

`<nav-bar data-route-name="{{$routeName}}" :route-name="{{$routeName}}"></nav-bar>`

when I inspect I do see `data-route-name="home"`, however, I keep getting this error:

[Vue warn]: Property or method "home" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

```
props: ['routeName'],
mounted() {
  console.log(this.routeName);
}
```

The console outputs `undefined` when the component loads up

Now my question is why does the console outputs undefined, why do I get the Vue warn, and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Just try passing like this:

```
<nav-bar :route-name="'{{$routeName}}'"></nav-bar>
```

You need send string with `''` (quotes)

Answer (score 0):

In props you should use attribute name not directly attribute value.

```
props: ['route-name'],
```

Comment: not sure about that, I get `NaN` from the console log. and the Vue warn is still showing

Answer (score 0):

You are using two templating engines in this case, Laravel Blade and Vue. You should read this section [Blade & Javascript Frameworks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks). When you are writing this, you are binding the data from Laravel to template.

```
<nav-bar data-route-name="{{$routeName}}" :route-name="{{$routeName}}"></nav-bar>

// After Laravel Blade Rendering you get:

<nav-bar data-route-name="home" :route-name="home"></nav-bar>

// This makes Vue warn because you did not declare data home
```

I guess you are trying to bind the data from Vue to template? You can add `@` to ignore the Laravel Blade rendering. I have also fixed some syntax, you should read the manual in [Vue: Template Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes).

```
<nav-bar data-route-name="@{{routeName}}" :route-name="routeName"></nav-bar>

// After Laravel Blade Rendering you get:

<nav-bar data-route-name="{{routeName}}" :route-name="routeName"></nav-bar>
```